# How can I use Json as Django view context

Tags: python, json, django

I have a string like:

```
daily_program = "{"Training Set":["abc","dxf","gfh"],"Nutrition Set":["acd","dbd","cdf"]}"
```

I want to use it as a context dictionary and pass it to the template in Django. Such as:

```
def program(request): 
    context = json.loads(daily_program)
    return  render_to_response('program.html',context,RequestContext(request))
```

Its acting like python Dict. when I print out the result. But I cant use it as a context in template such as:

```
<div>{{Training}}</div>
```

Is there any way to is use json object as a context dictionary ?

Comment: you can load it as a dict using `json.loads(daily_program)` then pass it into your template.

Comment: Seems good to me what you are doing. What do you mean by `But I cant use it as a context in template such as <div>{{Training}}</div>`? What happens when you do this?

Comment: you are aware of course that the code you posted isn't valid? The daily_program line has a syntax error

Comment: I have changed dictionary keys with spaced string.The problem occurs when I used keys with spaces. I am sorry to mislead you.

Answer (score 1):

`dialy_program` should read like so, with single quotes `''` to avoid a syntax error with building the string:

```
daily_program = '{"Training":["abc","dxf","gfh"],"Nutrition":["acd","dbd","cdf"]}'
```